# Using Twilio as call center backend how to reduce double cost for calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am using Twilio in a custom made app using the "Click to Call" feature where the agent will click a button in the web browser and their phone will ring and once they pick up a client from the list X is then  called.

My only concern is that although the app is working great and Twilio is working like a charm I noticed that I am been charged twice in my seudo call center. So, my question is:

What am I doing wrong? (or is this the way it works?)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Can you give a bit more detail on what you are seeing?

The way Twilio charges is per call "leg", with different prices for "inbound" (eg someone calls your Twilio number") or "outbound" (eg you have Twilio call someone) legs.  In your scenario it sounds like you have two outbound legs, one from Twilio to the agent and one from Twilio to the client.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, the way I have it Twilio call both the agent and the client and only logic is that I wait for the agent to answer first before calling the client. I trigger the both call from a click on a web browser the agent use to call the selected client.

Comment: If you are worried about cost and you know the agent is already in a browser you could look at integrating Twilio Client into the browser app rather than calling their phone.  As a VoIP solution, Client is less expensive so you'd be saving on that leg of the call.

Comment: @DevinRader can you please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147762/cannot-get-verification-code-in-twilio-trial-without-registering-number-on-twili